# Passing string to object as xml parameter

Tags: javascript, xml, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a string to a function to be used as a node parameter but it's undefined when concatenated with the object. If I type in the string value it works i.e., adlet.item[i].**deadBoltType** but when passed in it's undefined, what is the correct way to pass this string to be used as a node parameter(XML)? Thanks.

```
    function FilterResults(elementId, elementValue) {
                switch (elementId) {
                    case 'deadBoltType': LoadResults('deadBoltType', elementValue); break;

                }


    }

    function LoadResults(itemAttr, attrValue) {
        $('.results').detach();
        for (var i = 0; i < adlet.item.length; i++) {
            if (adlet.item[i].itemAttr == attrValue) { // itemAttr undefined                
                $('<div class="results">' +
                '<div class="result-image"><img scr="' + imgFolderPath + adlet.item[i].OMSID + '.jpg" width="100" height="80" alt="" />' + '</div>' +
                '<div class="result-brand">' + adlet.item[i].brand + '</div>' +
                '<div class="result-price">' + adlet.item[i].regularPrice +
                '</div>').appendTo("#view-lock-results");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, do:

`adlet.item[i][itemAttr]`

You're requesting a property, itemAttr, not a property named itemAttr.

`item[i].itemAttr !== item[i][itemAttr]`

`item[i].itemAttr === item[i]['itemAttr']`